# Centering items in a div above items in another div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to place a row of 6 text above 6 icons so that the first text will appear above the first icon, second text above second icon, etc. I can't post an image because I'm new here.

Here's the HTML:

```
 <div id="forecast">
  <!-- Naming convention starts with today as Sunday, because reasons -->
  <div id="names" class="row">
    <div id="mon" class="col-md-2"> Mon </div>
    <div id="tues" class="col-md-2"> Tues </div>
    <div id="wed" class="col-md-2"> Wed </div>
    <div id="thur" class="col-md-2"> Thur </div>
    <div id="fri" class="col-md-2"> Fri </div>
    <div id="sat" class="col-md-2"> Sat </div>
    </div>
  <!-- End of names -->

  <div id="forecast-icons" class="row">
    <div id="mon-icon" class="col-md-2"> </div> 
    <div id="tues-icon" class="col-md-2"> </div>
    <div id="wed-icon" class="col-md-2"> </div>
    <div id="thur-icon" class="col-md-2"> </div>
    <div id="fri-icon" class="col-md-2"> </div>
    <div id="sat-icon" class="col-md-2"> </div>

  </div>
  <!-- forecast icons -->
```

The bootstrap doesn't affect the icons, and I'm not sure why. To counteract this, I've tried to add padding-left: in both percentages and raw numbers, but those didn't work. I could do raw numbers, but that would require a STUPID amount of breakpoints.

I've also tried: #names, #forecast-icons{ display: flex; flex-direction: row; justify-content: center; }

But the icons were all bunched up in the center.

Here's a link to the codepen (I know people here like jsfiddle, sorry): https://codepen.io/CrumrineCoder/pen/EyLmoZ?editors=1100

And here's a full page view:

https://codepen.io/CrumrineCoder/pen/EyLmoZ?editors=1100

I have them all in a line by applying display: inline to all of them.

Comment: Here's a link to an image of what I'm trying to ask for: http://i.imgur.com/tX7Tf4c.png

Comment: Is the problem that the icons aren't centered? The bootstrap columns are working..

Comment: You're using `col-md-*` which will only apply on screens above 992 pixels wide. Not sure if you were aware of that.

Comment: Not sure I understand your question, but in the codepen you posted the icon divs take the width of 2 columns as you have assigned. They have a height on 1px and I did not see any icons included at all. If you add content or assign some height, you will see that they are right where they should be

Comment: The bootstrap columns are working for the icons for you?

Comment: Do you mind posting a picture of the columns working? Right now they're all on the left for me.

Comment: Nora, did you allow it to take geolocation? If so, did the rest of the things show things like temperature, the weather, location, time, etc?

Answer (score 0):

you could try to put your forecast names and icons in a table this should make them align somewhat properly underneath each other you can still add classes or id's to the table rows to center the text and icons more approperiatly

```
 <table>
  <tr bgcolor="#FF0000">
    <th>Mon</th>
    <th>T</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>icon</td>
    <td>icon</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: https://codepen.io/CrumrineCoder/pen/grzWqr?editors=1100 I tried this, but it didn't seem to work. Am I doing it wrong? Sorry, I'm comparatively new to web dev and I haven't delved into positioning too much.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so after working on this for awhile, I've fixed it... sorta. They're all aligned, but not really spaced out too much, but it works I guess. Here's the relevant CSS:

```
#names > div {
display: inline; 
font-size: 20px; 
}
#names{
  text-align: center; 
}
#forecast-icons > div {
  font-size: 30px; 

}
#forecast-icons{
  text-align: center; 
   display: block;
    width: 100%;
}
```